# Can I open the current post in Google Chrome from the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

Can I open the post I am viewing in the iOS app in Google Chrome?

I can currently only see the option to open it in Safari.

Comment: On my iPad, only Chrome shows up as an option... don't remember doing any tweak for that...

Comment: @brasofilo Weird. I'm using iPad mini 2.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, why the downvotes and why was it closed. Seems to be a good question.

Comment: You should read the revisions before other users came to clean up the mess @nic

Comment: @rand it was still quite understandable.

Comment: If you want to go demanding things in a threatening way, then yes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, on the app settings you should see this:

[image: settings page for SE app]

Comment: Thanks. Well i never thought that the option is here...